# using javascript select2 with ASPX calling a webmethod

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webmethod

I am trying to use select2 with ASPX calling a webmethod. I am not able to get the ajax web method called within the select2 java script method above. any idea what i am doing incorrectly ?

this is my control on the page

```
<input type="hidden" id="attendee" style="width:300px;" /
```

this is my javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#attendee').select2(
{
placeholder: 'Enter name', 
minimumInputLength: 1,
allowClear: true, 
ajax:{
type: "POST", 
url: "TestClientPage2.aspx/GetClientList",
dataType: 'json',
data: function (term, page) {
return {
pageSize: 20,
pageNum: page,
searchTerm: term
};
},
results: function (data, page) {
var more = (page * pageSize) < data.Total;
return { results: data.results, more: more };
}}});
```

});

This is my web method

```
public static string GetClientList(string searchTerm)
{
    return @"{""employees"": [{ ""firstName"":""John"" , ""lastName"":""Doe"" }]}";
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry..  i posted to soon.  My question is .. I am not able to get the ajax web method called within the select2 java script method above.  any idea what i am doing incorrectly ?

Comment: Modify your post so that question is included _in_ the post to make it easier for people to quickly help you. Cheers.